# State with nom (>5) and `alt`

Tags: rust, nom

After trying some tree structures in Rust, I finally decided to built up a linearized tree, e.g. something like

```rust
struct AST {
  exprs: Vec<Expr>,
}

enum Expr {
    LiteralInt(i32),
    OpAdd(ExprRef, ExprRef),
}

struct ExprRef(usize);

impl AST {
   // ...
   fn add_expr(&mut self, expr: Expr) -> ExprRef {
      self.exprs.push(expr);
      ExprRef(self.exprs.len() - 1)
   }
}
```

Hence, when parsing an expression (e.g. `"+ + 3 4 1"`) the parsers needs to mutate `AST`, by pushing new expressions into it and using the `ExprRef` for further expressions.

So, I've thought of something like

```rust
fn literal_int(ast: &mut AST) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> IResult<&str, ExprRef> {
   move |input: &str| {
      // ...
      let expr_ref = ast.add_expr(/* ... */);
      // ...
      Ok((input, expr_ref))
   }
}
```

This works, as long as I don't use branching combinators, since, you might have guessed it already, there would be the need for multiple mutable borrows of `ast`! E.g.

```
fn factor(ast: &mut AST) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> IResult<&str, ExprRef> {
   move |input: &str| {
      alt((
         literal_int(ast),
         parens(ast, term) // cannot borrow `ast` as mutable again
         ))(input)
   }
}
```

I try to achieve parsing into this sort of `AST` with `nom`, so I'm open for any suggestions in the right direction, even if this means I have to go a different route with the parsers. But it seems that some state is involved here anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like `let lit = literal_int(ast); let parens = parens(ast, term);`, then in the capture `alt((lit, parents))(input)`?

Comment: I've tested it in my current implementation. Unfortunately, this leads to the same error, since the closure captures the mutable reference. : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such side effect are an anti pattern in a parser conbinator. You may use the wrong tool for your code style. it's the parser that own the `ast` that should mutate it, by sharing `ast` with your sub parser you ask for bug specially using `alt`.

[Nom linked issue](https://github.com/Geal/nom/issues/1419), note that if you really want to do that as Geal said you may use `Rc<RefCell<AST>>`.

You could also just do `alt()` manually it's just a bunch of `if`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It felt like an anti-pattern, this confirms it.